# How do I override the type of one of the Struct fields but keep the unknown values?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I have a message

```
message EchoResponse {
  string message = 1;
  google.protobuf.Struct jwtClaims = 2;
}
```

However, when I do

```
      final var jwtClaimsStruct = Struct.newBuilder();
      JsonFormat.parser()
              .merge(someJson, jwtClaimsStruct);
```

I get

```
{
    "message": "FFbarsdfasf",
    "jwtClaims": {
        "sub": "good",
        "exp": 1.664354816E9, 
        "iss": "http://localhost",
        "jti": "3dbecf85-d5f2-2109-5a21-0d135fb35e8a"
    }
}
```

The `exp` is converted to a double value, but I would want to keep it an `int64`.

Is there any way of forcing just `exp` to be a specific type and still allow arbitrary key-value pairs to be whatever they want?

Comment: `Struct` doesn't have any way of representing 64-bit integers specifically - it's meant to just mirror what's in JSON. Fundamentally, if you're trying to represent large 64-bit integers in JSON, you should use strings instead to avoid losing precision.